# Submit a form only one time - simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am building a website where each user can review several papers and answers some questions on each paper.

I want the user to be able to answer the questions of a specific paper only one time (i.e. he cannot submit the form more than once for the same paper).

However, I am not sure how to do so. I was thinking to add a boolean field `submitted` in my schema for the model `question` but it does not help much because when a user submits a new form, the value is always `false` (and thus he can submit more than one form for the same paper) .

**questions.new.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @project, @paper, @question], url: project_paper_questions_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :question_2, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "question 2" %>
        <%= f.input :question_3, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: " question 3%>
        <%= f.input :question_4, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"],label: "question 4 " %>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Send your review" %>
       </div>
<% end %>
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :paper
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are generating a new form for an user `user`, take input from `user` (maybe a select drop-down) to identify which `paper` he wants to submit to. Then check whether the user already submitted the form or not. If he already submitted the form show him a friendly error message, otherwise generate the form for that `paper`.